# DialogFragment not dismissing when touching outside

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` and when I do `setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)` and `setCancelableOnTouchOutside(true)` `setCancelable(true)` the dialog dismiss when I touch outside but if I change `setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.png_image)` the dialog dont dismiss when touching outside. What could be the problem?

Comment: Possibly due to the size of your drawable. Check with small size drawable.

Comment: Check your DialogFragment width and height. Maybe those match_parent.